# Is there a by-hand prove that $\Gamma(\mathbb{C}P^n,E)$ is finite dimensional for a holomorphic vector bundle $E$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables, sheaf-cohomology

Let $E$ be a finite holomorphic vector bundle (or more generally a coherent analytic sheaf) on a compact complex manifold $X$. By the Cartan-Serre finiteness theorem, the cohomology $H^q(X,E)$ is a finite dimensional vector space for any $q$, and in particular the space of global sections $\Gamma(X,E)=H^0(X,E)$ is finite dimensional.

The proof is based on Hodge theory or properties of Frechet spaces.

> > My question is, if we only consider $X=\mathbb{C}P^n$, could we prove that $\Gamma(X,E)$ is finite dimensional by a direct, elementary computation?

Comment: Do you consider a spectral sequence argument as a direct, elementary computation ?

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Yes. Could you remind me how to prove it by a spectral sequence argument?

Comment: I'm really sorry, in fact my argument works only for algebraic vector bundle, and maybe that's trivial in this case. (Of course using GAGA this is enough to prove the statement for algebraic one but GAGA is already heavy machinery).
Anyway, once you have it, if $E$ algebraic on $\Bbb P^n$, there is a resolution where each terms are sum of invertible sheaves (which it follows from the Beilinson spectral sequence, it's explained in Huybrecht's book on Fourier-Mukai transform), and the statement follows immediately using the long exact sequence.